# Select variables/columns in a dataframe by those with matching given factor levels

Tags: r, dataframe, select, levels

Possible to select variables in a dataframe by those matching certain factor levels, selecting columns based on their factor levels (*used or unused*)? I can [summarise by levels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27677078/8804118) or subset possibly [by rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19192545/8804118), but I wondered if columns could be selected from the dataframe, or at least list variables/columns, that have certain factor levels.

```
library(dplyr)
height <- c(132,151,162,139,166,147,122)
    weight <- c(48,49,66,53,67,52,40)
    gender <- c("male","male","female","female","male","female","male")
    gender2 <- c("female","male","male","male","male","female","male")
    genderx <- c("xfemale","malex","malex","male","male","xfemale","xfemale")


    df <- data.frame(height,weight,gender, gender2, genderx) %>% 
      rowid_to_column(., "ID")
```

something like (or not like)

```
%>% select (vars(levels ==(c("male", "female")))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `select_if`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    select_if(~ is.factor(.) && all(c("male", "female") %in% levels(.)))
```

Or it can be `any` as well

```
df %>% 
    select_if(~ is.factor(.) && any(c("male", "female") %in% levels(.)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @akrun